# Is 1 hour transfer time in MUC with Lufthansa enough?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, connecting-flights, munich, muc

I am traveling from Venice to Munich, Munich to Denver with a 1 hour layover in Munich. My flight from Venice to Munich is with Air Dolomiti and from Munich to Denver with Lufthansa. From my understanding I will have to cross passport control. Will one hour be enough time to make it to my next flight?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is that a single ticket?

Comment: I've personally flown VIE-MUC-LAX with 1h transfer on a single ticket and it worked out fine. Tight, but fine.

Comment: I traveled FMC-MUC-SFO with a 2hr connection and had some time for a beer and pretzel at the lounge. 1hr would be tight, but doable.

Comment: Probably not, if this isn’t a single ticket and you have checked luggage. If it *is* a single ticket then the airline thinks its doable.

Comment: You are correct about passport control.  It's likely to take a bit more time if you are not an EU/EEA/CH citizen or otherwise entitled to use the EU/EEA/CH passport queue, but the more important factor is probably the number of other passengers clearing at the same time, which is difficult to predict.

Answer (score 2):

As usual:

If those are separate tickets, just forget about it, end of story.

If the two flights are on a single ticket, the airline thinks it’s possible (it’s over their “minimum connection time” (MCT) for that combination).

If there are no delays it should be tight but fine.

If there are delays they should have personnel around to expedite things (skip queues etc.).

If you don’t make it (through no fault of yours of course) they will rebook you on the next available flight, so you may be delayed, but you will get there at no extra cost. Even if you have to stay overnight they will have to find and pay for a hotel for you.

And unless there are extraordinary circumstances, if you arrive at your final destination much later than scheduled, you could even be due compensation, which means the airline has every reason to make sure you don’t miss your connection.

Be prepared (know where you have to go, have all your paperwork ready, have the relevant apps on your phone so you can have up to date information timely, get a seat towards the front on the first flight…), but don’t worry, and let the airline worry about things for you.

Answer (score 1):

That should be no problem. The minimum connection time within terminal 2 at Munich Airport (both Air Dolomiti and Lufthansa use terminal 2) is 40 minutes, even if you have to go through immigration.

If your incoming flight is slightly delayed, I would also expect that the personnel at the airport will help you with a faster transfer.

Comment: But only if on one ticket.