# Is a 40-minute layover in Munich enough time to catch a flight to Greece?

Tags: munich

I’m traveling from the USA to Greece with only a 40-minute layover in Munich. Will that be enough time or will I miss my flight? Thanks.

Comment: There's a [very similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179404/is-1-hour-transfer-time-in-muc-with-lufthansa-enough) which says 40 minutes is enough. You'll presumably have to go through immigration, but if the journey is through-ticketed and luggage is likewise, it will be reckoned possible. It's certainly at the absolute minimum though. (For more information, is it on a single ticket, and which airline?)

Comment: Booked with single ticket? It changes a lot.

Comment: @StuartF The question you link is for a domestic-to-intl connection, not a intl-to-domestic

Answer (score 2):

If these are 2 separate tickets than you have no chance making this.

If it's a single ticket:

> will that be enough time or will I miss my flight?

No one knows for sure.

40 minutes is very tight and probably the minimum connection time. You need to clear Schengen immigration in Munich but you do not need to collect bags, go through customs or go through security again. So it all depends on whether your flight is on time, whether you deplane via a jet bridge or a bus (which is depressingly common in Munich), how the lines at immigration are, whether you need to ride the train to a different concourse (likely) and how far the hike to your departure gate is.

If things go well and you are fairly mobile, I'd give it 90%+ chance, but there is no room for errors or mishaps.

If you miss, it the airline will book you on the next available flight for free. It's probably a good idea to find out right now what that flight maybe, so you can react faster when it happens.

Comment: Some airlines are very pro-active when it comes to handling short connections and will have people waiting for you at the gate, escort you to the top of the queue/dedicated counters at immigration, and on to your next flight if they feel that's needed. Also it's quite common on short connections that even if you make it, your luggage won't, and will be on the next flight (which may be very easy to deal with or a lot more complex, depending on the circumstances).

Comment: also it depends where *to Greece*. If it is Athens, airline will probably have later options (usually flight from US arrives om the morning (but also *it depends*). But if you go in a small airport without many connections, I would not risk (you will get accommodation, but you lose one day of holiday)

Comment: @jcaron: it really depends on the airline. United used to be absolutely brutal. They stranded 6 passengers over night (and put them in hotels) instead of waiting another 2-4 minutes. Once my inbound was delayed but I made the connection with 2 or 3 minutes to spare. However, they had already given away my seat because "we didn't think you would make it".